# Can we use a self made corpus for training for LDA using gensim?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I have to apply LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) to get the possible topics from a data base of 20,000 documents that I collected.

How can I use these documents rather than the other corpus available like the Brown Corpus or English Wikipedia as training corpus ?

You can refer [this](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) page.

Comment: This question is a bit open-ended; you may be more likely to get answers if you can be more specific about what you've tried so far and what specific problem(s) you're having.

Comment: If you don't like it, just vote to close it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the import functions in the [API](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/apiref.html)?  What kind of format are your documents in?

Comment: Thank you for reopening this question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After going through the documentation of the Gensim package, I found out that there are total 4 ways of transforming a text repository into a corpus.

There are total 4 formats for the corpus:

1. Market Matrix (.mm)
2. SVM Light (.svmlight)
3. Blie Format (.lad-c)
4. Low Format (.low)

In this problem, as mentioned above there are total of 19,188 documents in the database.
One has to read each document and remove stopwords and punctuations from the sentences, which can be done using `nltk`.

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, similarities, models

##
##Text Preprocessing is done here using nltk
##

##Saving of the dictionary and corpus is done here
##final_text contains the tokens of all the documents

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(final_text)
dictionary.save('questions.dict');
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in final_text]
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('questions.mm', corpus)
corpora.SvmLightCorpus.serialize('questions.svmlight', corpus)
corpora.BleiCorpus.serialize('questions.lda-c', corpus)
corpora.LowCorpus.serialize('questions.low', corpus)

##Then the dictionary and corpus can be used to train using LDA

mm = corpora.MmCorpus('questions.mm')
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100, update_every=0, chunksize=19188, passes=20)
```

This way one can transform his dataset to a corpus that can be trained for topic modelling using LDA using gensim package.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Hi, you can have a look over [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#corpus-formats).

Comment: I've already looked there, but there are no examples (i.e. a few lines of file with a given format).  There is only an example of `mallet` on http://cscorley.github.io/2014/05/06/using-gensim-for-lda/.