# How to predict the topic of a new query using a trained LDA model using gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I have trained a corpus for LDA topic modelling using gensim.

Going through the tutorial on the gensim website (this is not the whole code):

```
question = 'Changelog generation from Github issues?';

temp = question.lower()
for i in range(len(punctuation_string)):
    temp = temp.replace(punctuation_string[i], '')

words = re.findall(r'\w+', temp, flags = re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE)
important_words = []
important_words = filter(lambda x: x not in stoplist, words)
print important_words
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('questions.dict')
ques_vec = []
ques_vec = dictionary.doc2bow(important_words)
print dictionary
print ques_vec
print lda[ques_vec]
```

This is the output that I get:

```
['changelog', 'generation', 'github', 'issues']
Dictionary(15791 unique tokens)
[(514, 1), (3625, 1), (3626, 1), (3627, 1)]
[(4, 0.20400000000000032), (11, 0.20400000000000032), (19, 0.20263215848547525), (29, 0.20536784151452539)]
```

I don't know how the last output is going to help me find the possible topic for the `question` !!!

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a function in python that gives the possible topic for a new query:

```
def getTopicForQuery (question):
    temp = question.lower()
    for i in range(len(punctuation_string)):
        temp = temp.replace(punctuation_string[i], '')

    words = re.findall(r'\w+', temp, flags = re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE)

    important_words = []
    important_words = filter(lambda x: x not in stoplist, words)

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('questions.dict')

    ques_vec = []
    ques_vec = dictionary.doc2bow(important_words)

    topic_vec = []
    topic_vec = lda[ques_vec]

    word_count_array = numpy.empty((len(topic_vec), 2), dtype = numpy.object)
    for i in range(len(topic_vec)):
        word_count_array[i, 0] = topic_vec[i][0]
        word_count_array[i, 1] = topic_vec[i][1]

    idx = numpy.argsort(word_count_array[:, 1])
    idx = idx[::-1]
    word_count_array = word_count_array[idx]

    final = []
    final = lda.print_topic(word_count_array[0, 0], 1)

    question_topic = final.split('*') ## as format is like "probability * topic"

    return question_topic[1]
```

Before going through this do refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254207/can-we-use-a-self-made-corpus-for-training-for-lda-using-gensim) link!

In the initial part of the code, the query is being pre-processed so that it can be stripped off stop words and unnecessary punctuations.

Then, the dictionary that was made by using our own database is loaded.

We, then, we convert the tokens of the new query to bag of words and then the topic probability distribution of the query is calculated by `topic_vec = lda[ques_vec]` where `lda` is the trained model as explained in the link referred above.

The distribution is then sorted w.r.t the probabilities of the topics. The topic with the highest probability is then displayed by `question_topic[1]`.

Comment: I get final = ldamodel.print_topic(word_count_array[0, 0], 1)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 when I use this function. What does that mean? sorry for dumb question.

Comment: Why are you creating all the empty lists and then over-writing them immediately after?

Comment: Sorry about that. I made this code when I was literally bad at python. This is a good chance to refactor this function. I'll update the function.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we just need topic with highest probability following code snippet may be helpful:

```
def findTopic(testObj, dictionary):
    text_corpus = []
    '''
     For each query ( document in the test file) , tokenize the 
     query, create a feature vector just like how it was done while training
     and create text_corpus
    '''
    for query in testObj:
        temp_doc = tokenize(query.strip())
        current_doc = []

        for word in range(len(temp_doc)):
            if temp_doc[word][0] not in stoplist and temp_doc[word][1] == 'NN':
                current_doc.append(temp_doc[word][0])

        text_corpus.append(current_doc)
    '''
     For each feature vector text, lda[doc_bow] gives the topic
     distribution, which can be sorted in descending order to print the 
     very first topic
    ''' 
    for text in text_corpus:
        doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(text)
        print text
        topics = sorted(lda[doc_bow],key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
        print(topics)
        print(topics[0][0])
```

The tokenize functions removes punctuations/ domain specific characters to filtered and gives the list of tokens. Here dictionary created in training is passed as parameter of the function, but it can also be loaded from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Anjmesh Pandey suggested a good example code. However the first word with highest probability in a topic may not solely represent the topic because in some cases clustered topics may have a few topics sharing those most commonly happening words with others even at the top of them. Therefore returning an index of a topic would be enough, which most likely to be close to the query.

`topic_id = sorted(lda[ques_vec], key=lambda (index, score): -score)`

The transformation of ques_vec gives you per topic idea and then you would try to understand what the unlabeled topic is about by checking some words mainly contributing to the topic.

`latent_topic_words = map(lambda (score, word):word lda.show_topic(topic_id))`

show_topic() method returns a list of tuple sorted by score of each word contributing to the topic in descending order, and we can roughly understand the latent topic by checking those words with their weights.